# Reliable SATA to USB adapter

Tags: usb-to-sata

Do you know any reliable models of SATA to USB adapters for 3TB 3.5" HDD-s?

I tried 2 different adapters before and they both died in a matter of 1-2 weeks.

My HDD is [here.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004RORMF6)

Comment: With SATA to USB adapters it's difficult to find out a reliable model just by analyzing model's characteristics, it's not a video card. So in my opinion you can only ask people if they've encountered a good specimen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thing. I've used two of them for years, they've survived a 24 hour flight to Australia and a 3 month ship cargo trip back to the Netherlands, and at least half a year of 24/7 use.

http://www.arp.nl/verbatim-sata-usb-3-0-hdd-enclosure-53101-5080584